# Android Speech Recognition Using USB Microphone

Tags: android, audio, voice, speech, alsa

I'm trying to use RecognizerIntent for speech input and have the audio come from an external USB microphone. Since I'm using a development board, there is no internal mic. Is it possible to set USB microphone as default Audio input? Maybe use tinyalsa to set sound card? I know you can record using MediaRecorder via USB, but that doesn't work with Speech Recognition API.

I'm using Android 5.1.

Thanks